# Is this possible to do in one query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class User
end

class Message
 belongs_to :sender, :class_name=> 'User'
 belongs_to :recipient, :class_name=> 'User'
end
```

I want to fetch all the buddies of a given user ordered by **most recent date of message what appears in conversation between given user and his buddy** and, if it possible in same query, to fetch the number of message in their conversation.

Now, I'm stuck at this:

```
Messages.all(:joins => :sender,
   :conditions => ['sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?', some_user.id, some_user.id],
   :select => 'users.*, sender_id, recipient_id, MAX(messages.created_at) as last_created, COUNT(messages.id) as messages_count', 
   :group => 'messages.sender_id, messages.recipient_id',
   :order => 'last_created DESC'
```

That query produce this output:

a)

```
users.* | sender_id | recipient_id | MAX(last_created) | messages_count
user1   | 1         | 2            | bla               | bla
user1   | 1         | 3            | bla               | bla
user1   | 1         | 4            | bla               | bla
```

Because models joined by `messages.sender_id = user.id` I have only *user1* records fetched but I need *user2*, *user3* and *user4* records in that special situation A when *user1* has only send messages to his buddies.

b)

```
users.* | sender_id | recipient_id | MAX(last_created) | messages_count
user2   | 2         | 1            | bla               | bla
user3   | 3         | 1            | bla               | bla
user4   | 4         | 1            | bla               | bla
```

In situation B, otherwise, i have what i want to have - all three buddies ordered by most recent date of message what appears in conversation between given user and his buddy.

c)

```
users.* | sender_id | recipient_id | MAX(last_created) | messages_count
user1   | 1         | 2            | bla               | bla
user3   | 3         | 1            | bla               | bla
user4   | 4         | 1            | bla               | bla
```

Situation C. user2 as buddy of user1 is missing cause `:joins => :sender`. Otherwise, if  `:joins => :recipient` would be missing user3 and user4. Thats the cracker. **It's no matter how we join models**. How to solve this situation in one query?

Comment: just one thing: it's `:class_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [select_extra_columns](http://github.com/kandadaboggu/select_extra_columns) gem to return join/aggregate columns. Assuming you have installed the gem, modify your User model as shown below.

```
class User
  select_extra_columns


  def friends_with_conversation
    User.all(
     :select => "users.*, b.last_message_at, b.message_count",
     :joins  => "
            RIGHT JOIN
             ( SELECT   IF(a.sender_id=#{self.id}, a.recipient_id, 
                             a.sender_id) AS friend_id, 
                        MAX(a.created_at) AS last_message_at, 
                        COUNT(a.id)       AS message_count
               FROM     messages AS a
               WHERE    a.sender_id = #{self.id} OR 
                        a.recipient_id = #{self.id}
               GROUP BY IF(a.sender_id=#{self.id}, a.recipient_id, 
                             a.sender_id)
             ) AS b ON users.id = b.friend_id
           ", 
      :order  => "b.last_message_at DESC",      
      :extra_columns => {:last_message_at=>:datetime, :message_count => :integer}
    )
  end  
end
```

Now you can make following calls to get the friend details.

```
user.friends_with_conversation.each do |friend|
  p friend.name
  p friend.last_message_at
  p friend.message_count
end
```

You need the gem to return `last_message_at` and `message_count` in the `User` object returned by the query.

**Edit**
I am not familiar with PostgresSQL. Cursory reading of the documentation suggests, following SQL might work.

```
:joins  => "
 RIGHT JOIN
 ( SELECT   CASE WHEN a.sender_id=#{self.id} 
                 THEN a.recipient_id 
                 ELSE a.sender_id 
            END               AS friend_id, 
            MAX(a.created_at) AS last_message_at, 
            COUNT(a.id)       AS message_count
   FROM     messages AS a
   WHERE    a.sender_id = #{self.id} OR 
            a.recipient_id = #{self.id}
   GROUP BY CASE WHEN a.sender_id=#{self.id} 
                 THEN a.recipient_id 
                 ELSE a.sender_id 
            END
 ) AS b ON users.id = b.friend_id
"
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it actually may work, but I develop in PostgreSQL and seems like it can't understand this syntax. Would you mind to add version of this query for PostgreSQL. Thanks again.

Comment: I have added the PostgresSQL to my answer

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Very complex answer and very helpful. And I discover, all works without select_extra_columns gem. Why do I need it anyway?

Comment: If you want to get `last_message_at` and `message_count` in the same query, then you need the gem. Without the gem, calls such as `friend.message_count` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want an alternative "joins" string (ie not `:joins => :sender`).
Would `:joins => :recipient` give the correct response for situation B?

If not - you can also pass in hand-crafted SQL to the `:joins` key and join the tables however you like.

Looks like there's a good tutorial covering joins here:
http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/04/24/database-agnostic-database-ignorant/

Comment: :joins => :recipient gives user1 for all records in B. So, it is incorrect. The whole trick in that:).